# Catch subclass of exception AND Exception in camel route

Tags: java, apache-camel

I have a camel route that I am using my own route builder to listen for the specific types of exceptions that I have created in my code.

so to my route, I have added

```
onException();
onMyTypeException();
```

I have also created the corresponding methods in my route builder

```
public OnExceptionDefinition onException(){
return onException(Exception.class)

....
public OnExceptionDefinition onMyTypeException(){
return onException(MyTypeException.class)
....
```

The problem is, onException() seems to catch everything, instead of letting me catch the more specific error first. The idea here being that in my system I have not accounted for every type of error, so if some get by, catch them in the onException()

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

Camel will look for the explicit exception match first...but I think your initialization of the clauses is the issue.  you shouldn't need to return them in your methods, etc...

overall, make sure you define your onException() clauses in the RouteBuilder's configure() method before any routes are setup...

see [this page](http://camel.apache.org/exception-clause.html) for more details...something like this...

```
public void configure() throws Exception {

    onException(Exception.class).handled(true).log("general exception!!!");
    onException(MyException.class).handled(true).log("my exception!!!");

    from("direct:start").to("bean:myBean");
    ...
}
```

Comment: I am not doing simple logging when I catch the simple exceptions. This is why I wanted to get that code out of my primary routebuilder - to keep it looking clean.

Comment: @Derek, you can define these in a helper method if you wish, just make sure that method is called from the start of the configure() method and using the RouteBuilder's context.  Also, I'd up to Camel 2.9.1 if possible...

Answer (score 0):

You can read overall about error handling with Camel here
http://camel.apache.org/error-handling-in-camel.html

And for using onException (which is also called exception clause) there is documentation here: http://camel.apache.org/exception-clause.html

However error handling in Camel is very flexible and elaborate. And also dealing and handling errors in integration use-cases is often hard. That is why we have devoted a full chapter in the Camel in Action book to cover this extensively. So if you got the book, then make sure to read chapter 5, it will help you a lot.

Comment: That is what I used as the basis of my implementation. Was this working as of Camel 2.6? That is the version I am using.

Comment: The book covered the latest Camel version at that time, which was Camel 2.5.0. You have to try out yourself with the Camel version you use if it works for you. We fix bugs and improves stuff in newer Camel releases (and a few times introduce new bugs etc.)